# /cgi-bin/file.py запускается, а сам корень: /cgi-bin/ выдает ошибку 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

Если запустить скрипт: /cgi-bin/file.py то запускается, а если без ничего, т.е. сам корень cgi-bin: /cgi-bin/ то выдает ошибку 403.

Теоретически должен был отобразиться список файлов в директории cgi-bin.

Должно ли так быть? Почему так происходит? Почему автоматически не запускается index.html через cgi-bin?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что листинг директории /cgi-bin/ запрещен в настройках веб-сервера.
-- КО